# Sql: search column that starts with digits

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with the sql below. Basically I have rows that contains strings according to the format: 129&c=cars. I only want the digits part, e.g. 129. The sql query is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $db_table . " WHERE id LIKE '" . $id . "%'");
```

Why doesn't % work? I can't use %...% because it catches too much.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a smartass, but be careful when build the query: If id comes directly from a user, you a providing an open door to SQL injection.

Comment: What do you mean % doesn't work? Doesn't it select the rows you expected?

Comment: no, it matches the wrong row. So the id 26 is matched with 136.

Comment: Is query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE '26%'` works as you expected?
How query which you build looks like in plain text? Maybe because of $id value/type after concatenation you get something different then expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually recommend using regular expressions fo the matching, but unfortunately, there is no way to capture the matching part with mysql. You will have to do the extraction in php. If you have an array containing all the results called `$array`:

```
$array = preg_replace('/^(\d+).*/', '$1', $array);
```

Comment: is $array the same as my variable called $result?

Comment: This worked - thanks! The problem is that i'm fetching the entire table and I'm wondering if the query can be optimzed somehow.

Comment: You can use the limit statement if you just want some of the rows:
http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MySQL 'regexp' stuff in the WHERE clause to reduce the amount of data retrieved to just the rows you want. The basic for of your query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '^$id&'
```

where $id is inserted by PHP and the data you want is always at the start of the field and followed by a &. If not, adjust the regex to suit, of course.

MySQL's regex engine can't do capturing, unfortunately, so you'll still have to do some parsing in PHP as soulmerge showed above, but with the  'where regexp' stuff in MySQL, you'll only have to deal with rows you know contain the data you want, not the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Using a query like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id >= '0' COLLATE UTF8_BIN
        AND id < ':' COLLATE UTF8_BIN
```

will return all strings that start with a digit and make your expression *sargable*, i. e. and index on `id` can be used.

This will make your query run faster.